# In C++, how to invoke a constructor function?

Tags: c++

Here is my coding:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using std::endl;
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::string;
using std::istream;
struct worker
{
   worker()=default;
   worker(istream &f);
   int data;
};
int main()
{
    worker a;
    cout<<a.data<<endl;
    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
worker::worker(istream&f)
{
   read(f,*this);
}
istream&read(istream &f,worker&student)
{
   f>>student.data
   return f;
}
```

But when I debug,it warns me that I haven't initialized the element of `a`. I know that I need to input the data through `worker(istream &f)`, but I don't know how to invoke the constructor function to initialize `a.data`.

Comment: I suggest you pick up a basic C++ book.

Comment: I 'm reading a basic C++  book now.

Comment: You can't possibly debug as the code can't possibly compile. Post real code, not some made-up stuff.

Comment: It's part of the coding.

Comment: No,I just don't know how to use worker(istream &f) to intialize a.data.

Answer (score 3):

> But when I debug, it warns me that I haven't initialized the element of `a`. I know that I need to input the data through `worker(istream &f)`

It's good that you realized the warning is really a problem. It's a warning from a syntactic point of view but it is an error from a semantic point of view.

The *I know that* part is ill-founded. You realized the need to initialize `a.data` but your approach to doing it is flawed.

> but I don't know how to invoke the constructor function to intiallize `a.data`.

First of all, you cannot call constructor on already constructed object. Constructors are used only to construct objects, not to be called again on an already constructed object.

Secondly, use a different strategy to initialize the object. Remove the constructor `worker(istream&)` altogether. Use `read` on the already constructed object, such as:

```
int main()
{
    worker a;
    read(std::cin, a);
    std::cout << a.data << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Further refinement.

Instead of `read`, use `operator>>`.

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& f, worker& w)
{
   f >> w.data;
   return f;
}
```

Then, you can use:

```
int main()
{
    worker a;
    std::cin >> a;
    std::cout << a.data << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: imho an answer should mention why OPs code is terribly broken. In general warningns are just warnings and not errors, but in this case the warning should be taken serious

Comment: @tobi303, thanks for the prod.

Comment: Your answer is valuable，but I still want to know why I can't use worker(istream &f) to  explicitly intialize the value in the worker class.

Comment: @karel, you can use `a = worker(std::cin);`, but it is not a good idiom to use. Please note that you still can't use `a.worker(std:::cin);`.